# Using Carrierwave to upload image and that works but I don't know how to call the :thumb method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hello here is what I want to do...  I have a method that checks if the image is added or not if not the placeholder is used.

I would like to make it where if the image is uploaded on the index page the :thumb version of the image is used and when in the show page the normal image size is used.

I have

```
image_uploader.rb

include CarrierWave::RMagick
version :thumb do
process :scale => [335, 182]
end

articles_helper

def image_for(article)
if article.image.blank?
image_tag('placeholder.jpg')
else
image_tag(article.image)
end
end

index.html.erb

<p>
<%= link_to image_for(article), article %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image_tag(article.image)
```

will be like

`image_tag(article.image.thumb)` or `image_tag(article.image(:thumb))`

both versions are work